# iDangero.us Swiper multiple instances

Tags: jquery, swiper.js

I'm trying to add multiple swipers (http://www.idangero.us/swiper/) on my site. I want to add the swipers dynamic so i use the same class for every swiper. Each swiper looks like this:

```
    <div class="swiper-container">
        <div class="swiper-wrapper">
            <div class="swiper-slide">
                Slide 1
            </div>
            <div class="swiper-slide">
                Slide 2
            </div>
            <div class="swiper-slide">
                Slide 3
            </div>
            <div class="swiper-slide">
                Slide 4
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Add Pagination -->
        <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
        <!-- Add Arrows -->
        <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
        <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
    </div>
```

If i want to initialize just one swiper everything works fine with this code:

```
var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
    pagination: '.swiper-pagination',
    paginationClickable: '.swiper-pagination',
    nextButton: '.swiper-button-next',
    prevButton: '.swiper-button-prev',
    loop: true
});
```

What i want is to instantiate multiple swipers on one page, like this:

```
var swipes = [];
$('.swiper-container').each(function(i, obj){
    swipes[i] = new Swiper(obj, {
        pagination: '.swiper-pagination',
        paginationClickable: '.swiper-pagination',
        nextButton: '.swiper-button-next',
        prevButton: '.swiper-button-prev',
        loop: true
    });
});
```

But this doesn't work for me. I think the propertys are causing problems. Maybe i should do something like this to be more specific and just use to pagination / nextButton / ... inside the current swiper and not on the whole site:

```
pagination: obj + '.swiper-pagination',
paginationClickable: obj + '.swiper-pagination',
nextButton: obj + '.swiper-button-next',
...
```

But i don't know exactly how to do it. How can i do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you need to do something like:

```
$('.swiper-container').each(function(){
    new Swiper($(this), {
        pagination: $(this).find('.swiper-pagination'),
        paginationClickable: $(this).find('.swiper-pagination'),
        nextButton: $(this).find('.swiper-button-next'),
        prevButton: $(this).find('.swiper-button-prev'),
        loop: true
    });
});
```

Comment: swiperContainer.each(function(){
                new Swiper($(this), {
                  slidesPerView: 5,
                  spaceBetween: 45,
                  watchOverflow: true,
                  navigation: {
                    nextEl: $(this).find('.js-swiper-scroll-next'),
                    prevEl: $(this).find('.js-swiper-scroll-prev')
                  }
                });
              }) 

I tried with this. But still not working.

Comment: i want to attach one common navigation for all of them but navigation only two way binds to the last initialized slider.when i click on arrows/bullets then all sliders update but when i swipe the sliders, bullets are not updating.