# how to set few image swipers in the same page

Tags: javascript, html

Im using the idangarus swiper. i made one swiper and i duplicated it 3 times.
my problem is the following:
when i play (swipe) the swiper, all the swipers moves also. i want to every swiper to work alone. I am not familiar with js so i need some help.

the js file is:

```
var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
pagination: '.swiper-pagination',
paginationClickable: '.swiper-pagination',
nextButton: '.swiper-button-next',
prevButton: '.swiper-button-prev',
spaceBetween: 30,
effect: 'fade'
});
```

the html file is:

```
        <!-- Swiper -->
    <div class="swiper-container">
        <div class="swiper-wrapper">
            <div class="swiper-slide" style="background-image:url(images/1.jpg)"></div>
            <div class="swiper-slide" style="background-image:url(http://lorempixel.com/1000/1000/nightlife/2)"></div>
            <div class="swiper-slide" style="background-image:url(http://lorempixel.com/1000/1000/nightlife/3)"></div>
            <div class="swiper-slide" style="background-image:url(http://lorempixel.com/1000/1000/nightlife/4)"></div>
            <div class="swiper-slide" style="background-image:url(http://lorempixel.com/1000/1000/nightlife/5)"></div>
        </div>
        <!-- Add Pagination -->
        <div class="swiper-pagination swiper-pagination-white"></div>
        <!-- Add Arrows -->
        <div class="swiper-button-next swiper-button-white"></div>
        <div class="swiper-button-prev swiper-button-white"></div>
    </div>
```

thank you.

Answer (score 0):

What you will want to do is create three different instances of the Swiper object and have each object reference different swippers on the page.

Right now the swiper object is created by referencing the various classes associated with the different parts of the swiper (e.g. the pagination, arrows, container)

You'll want to create custom identifiers (e.g. using different ids for each part) and create each swiper referencing their respective components with their respective ids.

Essentially, you'll have something that looks like this:

```
<div id="swiper1">// all the other divs with their respective ids</div>
<div id="swiper2">// all the other divs with their respective ids</div>
<div id="swiper3">// all the other divs with their respective ids</div>
```

And then when you create your swiper objects, you'll have something like:

```
var swiper1 = new Swiper("#swiper1", {// rest of object});
var swiper2 = new Swiper("#swiper2", {// rest of object});
var swiper3 = new Swiper("#swiper3", {// rest of object});
```

Comment: there is any way to do this with "this" function? i mean, one script for all swipes that tell them to play (swipe) only the specific swiper?

Comment: I don't understand your question. The "this" keyword isn't a function but rather context (which depends where "this" is). "this" is just an object :)

Comment: hey, sorry for the delay. i saw this answer: [link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30885041/idangero-us-swiper-multiple-instances) and there is a $this object. i tried to use it but without succeed. this script should work for all the swipers.

Comment: Ah. You meant $(this). What it does is let's you reference the jquery selector you just used. In the example below, you search for an html element with the class foo and when you click it, it says to take whatever html element with class foo that you clicked and change the color.

$('.foo').click(function(){
    $(this).css('color', '#000');
}

Comment: If you want to have three different swipers, you will need to instantiate three different Swiper objects. What do you not understand from what I've said or what has been said in the other post?