# Swiper slider: how to initialize it on multiple dynamic instances but named

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to initialize multiple Swiper instances.

I found a solution based on jQuery `.each()` here:

[iDangero.us Swiper multiple instances](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30885041/idangero-us-swiper-multiple-instances)

But using this code I can't use a Swiper's methods because I can't write something like that `mySwiper.update();`

My code below:

```
$('.results-tab-slider').each(function() {
  new Swiper($(this), {
    slidesPerView: 2,
    spaceBetween: 70,
    loop: true,
    breakpoints: {
      767: {
        slidesPerView: 1
      },
      1024: {
        slidesPerView: 2
      },
      1270: {
        slidesPerView: 1
      }
    },
    navigation: {
      prevEl: $(this).siblings('.results-tab-button-prev'),
      nextEl: $(this).siblings('.results-tab-button-next'),
    }
  });
});
```

As I said I want to rewrite the code I can use instances like this `mySwiper.update();`
The most important thing is that I don't know how much sliders is generated.

Comment: have you solved this? In case could you post an answer? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Add how many Swipers you want in the DOM. Be sure that each of them have a different ID.

```
<div id="swiper-a" class="swiper-container">
  <div class="swiper-wrapper">
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 1</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 2</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 3</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="swiper-b" class="swiper-container">
  <div class="swiper-wrapper">
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 1</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 2</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Then in your JS:

```
 var thisSwiper = [];
 $('.swiper-container').each(function(i) {
   var this_ID = $(this).attr('id');

   thisSwiper[i] = new Swiper('#'+this_ID, {
     loop: true,
     direction: 'vertical'
   });

   thisSwiper[i].on('slideChange', function () {
     console.log('slide '+i+' changed');
   });
 });
```